# Extract the rows with filtering more than two conditions

Tags: pandas

Data frame is below

```
name,id_number
Tom,ABC1234567
Mak,None
Sim,ABC
None,20110159893
```

Cases

1. Name should not `None`
2. id_number should not `None`
3. id_number should not less than `4 numbers`

Expected Out

`df['out']`

```
Tom,ABC1234567
```

How to write a function and apply with one condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and test by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater:

```
df = df[df['name'].notna() & df['id_number'].notna() & df['id_number'].str.len().gt(4)]
print (df)
  name   id_number
0  Tom  ABC1234567
```

Alternative:

```
df = df[df[['name','id_number']].notna().all(axis=1) & df['id_number'].str.len().gt(4)]
```

Comment: @jezreal how to improve the coding skill, do you have any suggestion. I have the logic, while writing I will get stuck

Comment: hmm, i thought `df['id_number'].str.contains('\d\d\d\d+',na=False)` last condition :)

Comment: @Maws - I think it need 2 things - a lot of coding for experience and time, also some tutorials are relly good like [this](https://www.dataschool.io/)

Answer (score 0):

```
you need,
df = df.replace('None',np.nan)
df[df.notnull().all(axis=1) & (df['id_number'].str.len() > 3) ]
```